# creating simple tag cloud in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create tag cloud in css.

For example If i have 5 links `(<a href)` in same line , I want one to appear little up and another link little down , but in same line.I tried `padding-top:20px` and `display:block` but its making the link move to next line.

[image]

```
 <style>
    .cloud
    {
    height:200px;
    }
    .cloud1
    {
    font-size:26px; 
    margin-top:2px;
    }
    .cloud2
    {
    font-size:18px; 
    margin-top:5px;
    }
    </style>




   <div class="cloud">
     <a class="cloud1" target="_blank" href="">Movie</a> </span>
     <a class="cloud2" target="_blank" href="">news</a> </span>
     <a class="cloud2" target="_blank" href="">Movie</a> </span>
     <a class="cloud1" target="_blank" href="">123</a> </span>
    <br>
     <a class="cloud1" target="_blank" href="">rand</a> </span>
     <a class="cloud2" target="_blank" href="">news</a> </span>
     <a class="cloud2" target="_blank" href="">Movie</a> </span>
     <a class="cloud1" target="_blank" href="">ok</a> </span>

     </div>
```

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/fznjydyd/ to play.I tried various things in display,position,margin,padding .But nothing seems to help me.

Comment: For the one who voted to close this question.I have edited my question.

Comment: You can use `position:relative` to adjust the position ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrczg3wx/)) but there's no way you can achieve what you see on the screenshot with purely CSS unless you manually apply the style for each of the item to position them.

Comment: @Billy : yea I want exactly like that..but its overlapping when resized

Comment: I don't get what you mean. When you resize, of course it will break into a new line if the width is reduced (hence possibly overlap). Otherwise, you'll need to have a fixed-width container to prevent this issue. Or you could use media queries and set different arrangement if the width is too small.

Comment: What does the expected output look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can set position: relative to `.cloud` , `position: absolute` to `.cloud-X` and then give it the position desired to each.

like this

```
<div class="cloud">
    <a href="" class="tag cloud1">aaaaa</a>
    <a href="" class="tag cloud2">bbbbb</a>
    <a href="" class="tag cloud3">ccccc</a>
    <a href="" class="tag cloud4">ddddd</a>
    <a href="" class="tag cloud5">ddddd</a>
</div>

.cloud{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.tag{
    position: absolute;
}

.cloud1{
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
}

.cloud2{
    right: 10px;
    top: 15px;
}

.cloud3{
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 55px;
}

.cloud4{
    top: 90px;
    left: 155px;
}

.cloud5{
    top: 70px;
    left: 65px;
}
```

It is hard to do if you have to many tags but it works, and you can do it.

[I code this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/b14tc86s/3/) to show you that you can. :)